# Git - my css file is showing as one single line

Tags: git, github

I have a normal looking CSS file. When I make changes though, in git it shows as if the ENTIRE file is one single line. Really annoying since I can't do much comparisons or merging with it.

Comment: I don't understand what you were trying to say. How else should git treat every line as a single line? Or do you meant *all* lines as a single line? It might be helpful if you can post sample of your CSS file and/or sample of how git is showing it to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Are you viewing a file created in Linux with for example notepad.exe?

Comment: Yeah the entire file shows up as a single line. I'm using Coda, and Tower.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your editor.  It is probably using auto-formatting, but without introducing line feed or carriage return.  In such case, you should check your editor options to introduce line feed (\n) or introduce them yourself manually.

in order to check it, try opening the offending file with a different editor, or a tool that can show the test as it is, for instance, using `more` or `less` in a terminal.

Comment: Hmm thanks! So it was set at unicode 8. I switched it to "Western (Mac OS Roman)" (what my other files were encoded as) and now Git shows the lines. Any explanation?

Comment: That sounds weird.  I would bet for a bug in the editor, given its concept of smart tabs.  Unicode (or UTF-8) should not be a problem, it is what I use by default.  How did the file look if you opened with a different editor (when it was unicode)?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using gitk to view commit history and try meld to merge files

Comment: sorry, I had assumed that you were using Ubuntu or some other Linux derivative, these solutions would make sense if you were using Linux. My Bad :) So, I'm not sure what kind of tools are available on Mac, but basically GIT will not display whitespace, you need a repository viewer to see the original layout